# Appropriate license for project using assets not available for commercial use

Tags: mit, commercial, assets

I have a project which I would like to open source under the MIT license. However, it uses assets (images) which are available only for personal use, not for commercial.

Is the MIT license safe? Can I somehow state, that the assets are unavailable for commercial purposes? Is there a license that handles these issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A permissive license like MIT/X11 is a perfectly suitable choice. Consider that permissively-licensed code may be freely combined with proprietary components. The situation is no different here. (If you wanted to use a copyleft license like the GNU GPL, you might need to grant an exception to allow distribution of your GPL'd code with the nonfree assets, but a permissive license like MIT/X11 already grants such permission by default.)

Where you need to take care is in clearly indicating *which* files are licensed which way, and communicating to recipients that the project as-is cannot be redistributed for commercial purposes due to the proprietary license on the art assets. Communicating this information is not within the purview of a license document itself, which indicates what use is allowed, but belongs in a separate document that says which license terms correspond to which files. Include this information in your `README`, `LICENSING` file, or other prominent document.